# How to manage image size as per screen size

Tags: android, eclipse

Images diplay fine on a s3 tab, but when I tried in smaller screen it gives similar image size which takes it to beyond the screen.

```
itemImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageId);
```

Please advise me on how to manage image sizes as per screen size.

```
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ItemId"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/img_001" />
```

Comment: Please post your xml file code such that you can get much better explanation regarding your question.

Comment: @user3541465 here is xml please see above

Comment: You have different images for different resolutions?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at these links , This might be helpfull

http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

You can make multiple layouts. For example one for small screen, another for medium and another for large screen. You basically only have to change the sizes but you could also for example make a two cols layout for large screen to make it nice.
The android select automaticaly the layout.
Se this  [http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.htm](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)

It is also a good practice to use diferent image sizes for diferent screen density.

Answer (score 0):

Android does not resize the image. You have to resize the image before you display.